# visual studio Regex Find/Replace error

Tags: visual-studio, regex, replace

I'm working on using Find/Replace to change a bunch of labels to DataBound text.

Basically I'm trying to convert something like

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl213" runat="server" />
```

to

```
<%# Eval("_213")%>
```

**Here's my regex**

```
<asp:Label ID="lbl{\d*}" runat="server" />
```

**Here's my replace**

```
<%# Eval("_\1")%>
```

**Here's my Error**

> > Unknown argument for ':' operator. Complete Regular Expression required in the search string.

How would I resolve this?

**EDIT:**
I also tried the following

```
<asp{\:}Label ID="lbl{\d*}" runat="server" />
```

but the response is that

> > The specified text was not found.

Comment: I don't know ASP, which is why I'm just putting this in a comment, but... it sounds like maybe you just need to escape the colon, like: \:

Comment: I did try escaping the colon... no dice.  I tried **FIND**`<asp{\:}Label ID="lbl{:z}" runat="server" />` **REPLACE**`<%# Eval("\2")%>`, but still no luck

Comment: What about removing the colon altogether, just to see if it would work? Sorry I can't be more helpful; I really don't know VC or ASP at all. Maybe it would help if you pasted the actual code that's using that regex? Two other things that come to mind: the / maybe needs escaping, and, the backslashes may need to be escaped themselves; as in \\.

Comment: Thanks for trying.  There is no "code" that is using the regex.  I'm using the Regular Expression "Find / Replace" feature that's built into Visual Studio.  I did try escaping the backslash, but I can't seem to make it work that way either.  Very confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression:

```
\<asp\:Label ID="lbl{:d+}" runat="server" /\>
```

will work just fine as well. You only need to escape the colon and the angle brackets.

Answer (score 2):

Well holy crap.  You basically have to escape EVERYTHING that's not a text character

```
\<asp\:Label ID\=\"lbl{:z}\" runat\=\"server\" \/\>
```

Comment: Be aware that Visual Studio's regex flavor is very atypical.  In most of the regex flavors you see mentioned here, the colon and angle bracket characters have no special meaning unless they're part of some regex construct like `(?:...)` (non-capturing group) or `(?<=...)` (lookbehind), so there's no need to escape them.